# Kohana 3 routing error with default controller in controller subdirectory

Tags: routes, kohana-3

I am receiving "HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL admin/index, controller_admin was not found on this server." when I try to access **www.site.com/admin**. **www.site.com/admin/home** works fine.

I am assuming that it should find the Controller_Admin_Home controller but it seems my admin route is being ignored in the default case. Any ideas?

My Routing rules:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin/(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action' => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))(/<format>)', array('format'=>'html|json','id'=>'[0-9]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action' => 'index',
    'id' => null,
    'format' => null,
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The default case" means what excactly?

Your admin route matches everything that starts with "admin/" and had a maximum of three adittional segments. Notice the slash?

Move the slash one position to the right and it will be as optional as the controller parameter.